# How to solve issue of "PLAYER_ERROR_SEEK_FAILED" when forward/backward media in Tizen TV?

Tags: avplayer, tizen, tizen-web-app

I am using AV player in tizen TV application. When I forward/backward media then I am getting this error "PLAYER_ERROR_SEEK_FAILED"
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: did you figure this out? Doesn't seem to matter what state the player is in. I always have this error.

Comment: @Andrew: Which device do you use to run app?

Comment: 2018 Samsung Smart TV

Comment: **@Andrew:** I think, this should work fine in real device because I am facing this issue in emulator and when I run my app in real device, it is working properly there. Emulator might not support all feature like real device that's why I am facing this issue in emulator.

Comment: it doesn't work on the emulator or the device for me. Same error on both saying "invalid state" even though the state is "playing".

Comment: **@Andrew:** Have you tried given solution which mentioned in answers? If you already tried that, can you please share your sample code and error log?

Comment: Posted a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548191/unable-to-change-the-playhead-location-using-samsung-avplay-api

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/api-references/samsung-product-api-references/avplay-api

PLAYER_ERROR_SEEK_FAILED : Failed to perform seek operation, or seek operation called during an invalid state.

You should make sure the player is in a valid state.

Can be called in the following states: "IDLE","READY", "PLAYING" (buffered data is flushed and buffering starts over).

Comment: PAUSED is also mentioned as a valid state for seek operation.

Answer (score 1):

Be cautious about this part of the docs for `seekTo`, `jumpForward`, and `jumpBackward`:

https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/api-references/samsung-product-api-references/avplay-api

> During this async operation, the other API would not be allowed. So, the application needs to wait for one of both callbacks( SuccessCallback, errorCallback) before any other API call.

If you execute multiple seeks you must await the previous one to call back.